# Different globalAlpha for different canvases

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need my text overlay to be of a different color and different globalAlpha value than the canvas overlay. However, `textOverlay` is inheriting property from the canvas, how can I prevent that and set different properties for each?

JS Code example:

```
function draw(cordOne, cordTwo, cordThree, n) {

  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let textOverlay = document.getElementById("text");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let textOverlay = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.globalAlpha = 0.1;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(cordOne[0], cordOne[1]);
    context.lineTo(cordTwo[0], cordTwo[1]);
    context.lineTo(cordThree[0], cordThree[1]);
    context.closePath();

    let centerX = (cordOne[0] + cordTwo[0] + cordThree[0]) / 3;
    let centerY = (cordOne[1] + cordTwo[1] + cordThree[1]) / 3;

    textOverlay.font = "20px Arial Black";
    textOverlay.fillText(n, centerX, centerY);

    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.strokeStyle = "#666666";
    context.stroke();

    // the fill color
    context.fillStyle = "#22234";
    context.fill();
    }
 }

 draw([35, 49], [168, 49], [168, 128], 1);
 draw([35, 49], [140, 49], [140, 115], 2);
```

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
  <div class="stack">
    <canvas id="text" width="1000" height="700">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="700">
    </canvas>
  </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
.stack {
  position: relative;
}
.stack canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you set the context of the text overlay as the canvas context the fix would be to change `let textOverlay = canvas.getContext("2d");` to `let tCtx = textOverlay.getContext("2d");` Where `textOverlay` is the textOverlay canvas.

Example:

```js
function draw(cordOne, cordTwo, cordThree, n) {

  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let textOverlay = document.getElementById("text");
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let t = textOverlay.getContext("2d");

    context.globalAlpha = 0.1;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(cordOne[0], cordOne[1]);
    context.lineTo(cordTwo[0], cordTwo[1]);
    context.lineTo(cordThree[0], cordThree[1]);
    context.closePath();

    let centerX = (cordOne[0] + cordTwo[0] + cordThree[0]) / 3;
    let centerY = (cordOne[1] + cordTwo[1] + cordThree[1]) / 3;

    t.font = "20px Arial Black";
    t.fillText(n, centerX, centerY);

    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.strokeStyle = "#666666";
    context.stroke();

    // the fill color
    context.fillStyle = "#22234";
    context.fill();
    }
 }

 draw([35, 49], [168, 49], [168, 128], 1);
 draw([35, 49], [140, 49], [140, 115], 2);
```

```css
.stack {
  position: relative;
}
.stack canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
    <canvas id="text" width="1000" height="700">
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="700">
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that even though you have two `canvas` tags with different ids and even though you are initializing variables correctly

```
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let textOverlay = document.getElementById("text");
```

in your `if` you redeclare them to be the `context` of the same `canvas`:

```
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let textOverlay = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //Further code
  }
```

but you need to fix the reinitialization of `textOverlay`:

```
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let textOverlay = textOverlay.getContext("2d");
    //Further code
  }
```